# Parsing Date Formats in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to convert Dates into Unix Timestamps in Java. Examples for my dates are: "Fri Jun 05 15:53:07 PDT 2009"

My code is:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString );
long unixTime = (long) date.getTime()/1000;
System.out.println("Unix Time: " + unixTime );
double unixFloat = unixTime;
```

The given error is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jun 05 15:53:07 PDT 2009"
```

What's the right Pattern?

Comment: dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy according to the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()

Comment: Ur code works for me. Perhaps u assign `dateString` to some other value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Locale`, Some cases if you are not set the locale you may face this kind of issues.

Eg:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
                                                                     ,Locale.US);
```

From `Java` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> SimpleDateFormat also supports localized date and time pattern
>   strings. In these strings, the pattern letters described above may be
>   replaced with other, locale dependent, pattern letters.
>   SimpleDateFormat does not deal with the localization of text other
>   than the pattern letters; that's up to the client of the class.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Locale issue - `Fri` is friday in English but not in French or German for example:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```